# What is the best way to generate a random integer within a range and exclude a specific integer in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

I currently have the following function, but is there a more efficient way to generate a random integer within a range and exclude a specific integer in Matlab?

```
function aNew = random(a)
aMin = a-100;
aMax = a+100;
aNew = a;
while aNew == a
    aNew = randi([aMin, aMax]);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `randsample` to draw samples from a specified distribution.

Something like this should work fine

```
sampleRange = [1, 100];  % sample from 1 to 100
noSample = 50; % lets exclude 50
pop2Sample = [range(1):noSample-1, noSample+1:range(2)]; %create the population

sample = randsample(pop2Sample,1); %draw a single sample
```

**Update**

If you wanted to exclude multiple values from your population  you could use the `setdiff` function.

```
pop2Sample = 1:100;  % sample from 1 to 100
noSample = 0:10:100 % lets exclude any all multiples of ten
pop2Sample = setdiff(pop2Sample, noSample);

sample = randsample(pop2Sample,1); %draw a single sample
```

Comment: This doesn't seem more efficient since it creates a population.

Comment: @idealistikz its more efficient in the sense that it executes using the same number of commands on each execution. Using a while loop it is possible to randomly generate the excluded number several times in a row, this means that the execution time of your algorithm may vary each time you call it.

Comment: This is theoretically correct and computationally efficient. You can enhance by `sample = randsample(pop2Sample, N, true)` so you can draw `N` samples with replacement, thus uniformly (by independent trials) from `pop2Sample` value distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Your current method does rejection sampling. Why don't you do this: Suppose the range of integers you want to draw samples from is `[a, c]` and the number you want to exclude is `b`. Then sample from `[a, c-1]` and for every sample larger than or equal to `b`, increment it by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this:

```
function aNew = random(a, sz)

    if nargin == 1, sz = [1 1]; end

    aMin = a-100;
    aMax = a+100;

    aNew = randi([aMin aMax-1], sz);

    aNew(aNew == a) = aMax;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @slayton 's solution, for uniform sampling on `N` samples, with replacement, you can randomly index, with replacement, inside the value population:

```
N = 10; % samples
aMin = -100; % lower
aMax = +100; % upper
a = 0; % excluded int 

valPop = [aMin:a-1, a+1:aMax]; % value population
samples = valPop(randi([1, N-1], 1, N)); % with resampling
```